# Will the destructor of an object be called if a function returns early or throws an exception?

Tags: c++, destructor

In the following code, I use a *wrapper object* to temporarily store some stuff from a db in memory. My question is simple:

Can I be sure that the destructor is called? I am particularly worried about cases where
a) `testCondition` is true and the function returns early from an inner scope of the scope in which `tempObj` was constructed
b) some runtime error occurs during the execution of this function (which is caught at a higher level)

(As a side question: is this a good way to temporarily store some data? In my application, `someFunc()` is a save/export function of the current db.)

```
class TempStore
{
public:
    TempStore() {/* delete some stuff from a db and store this in memory*/}
    ~TempStore() {/* write this stuff back into the db*/}
};

void someFunc(bool testCondition)
{
    TempStore tempObj = TempStore();
    // some code
    if (testCondition)
        return; //early return
    // some more code
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding logs (printf for example or writing to a file) and debug? In the code that you shown the destructor will be called.

Comment: What do you mean by runtime error? C++ exceptions? Then it will work. If your program really fails, seg fault etc. then it won't work.

Comment: Yes, `TempStore`'s destructor will be called when the `someFunc()` function returns, assuming "normal" program execution (*e.g.* no crashes or segmentation faults). This is called [the "Resource Acquisition Is Initialization" (RAII) idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), and it is a cornerstone of modern C++.

Comment: Yes, I have, and it seems to be doing fine. But as I have only started collaborating on a large project for which I don't know yet all dependencies and possible Runtime errors and quirks, I was hoping to obtain some "syntactical guarantee" that my object will be destructed in any case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The destructor of an automatic object will be called when the program leaves the object's scope. This includes returning from the function (early or otherwise), and leaving via an exception - as long as the exception is handled. In the case of an exception, it's called during *stack unwinding* before the exception is handled.

It might not be called in some cases, including:

- leaving via a call to `longjmp`; this gives undefined behaviour;
- leaving via an exception that's not handled; it's unspecified whether the stack is unwound.
- terminating the program (e.g. calling `exit`, or raising a signal that causes termination).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, destructor will be called. Every object, created on stack will be correctly destroyed if you early return. If exception is  thrown, destructor will be called after program execution arrived to the catch block.

Comment: This answer is incomplete and hence wrong. From the title: “Will the destructor of an object be called if a function … crashes?”

Comment: I think he's talking about exceptions not crash

Comment: Even for exceptions, this won't happen if the code is not running in a try block.

Comment: Sorry, the code is run within a try block at a higher level. I will adapt the title

Answer (score 2):

The destructor will be called unless the program blows up due to a seg fault or a power outage or whatever. Simply returning early from a function or throwing an exception is not enough to stop the destructor running.

This design is a bit flawed though, since writing to a database is an operation that could fail, and throwing an exception from a destructor is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: Could you suggest how I could handle such a case? What would happen if an exception is thrown from a destructor?